# Let $S=\{a,b,c\}$. How many different binary operations are there on $S$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I think it should go like this:

For a binary operation, we are creating ordered pairs with all of the possible elements. Our ordered pairs will then look like $(x,y)$ where $x$ and $y$ are possible elements from $S$. Since there are only $3$ possible choices for $x$ and $y$, there are $3^2$ or $9$ ordered pairs that can be formed, and since there are $2^n$ possible subsets of $S$ where $n$ is the number of elements, there are $2^9=512$ possible binary operations on $S$.

Does that work?

Comment: For every ordered pair $(a,b)$, there are $3$ choices for what the function sends $(a,b)$ to/

Answer (score 4):

You started well, but then you went a bit astray. A binary operation on $S$ isn’t a subset of $S\times S$: it’s a function from $S\times S$ to $S$. How many such functions are there? HINT: For each $\langle x,y\rangle\in S\times S$, how many choices are there for the outcome of the operation?

Comment: You could have $(x,x)$, $(x,y)$ or $(y,y)$. So three?

Comment: @TheMobiusLoops: The binary operation outputs values in $S$, not in $S\times S$, so these aren’t even possible outcomes.

Comment: Oh, so just $a,b$ and $c$.

Comment: @TheMobiusLoops: There you go. Yes, so there are indeed three possible function values for each of the nine ordered pairs. And that makes a total of how many functions (binary operations)?

Comment: $3^9=19683$. Thank you.

Comment: @TheMobiusLoops: Yep, you’ve got it. You’re welcome.

Comment: $19683$?? I would have never thought..